# Win Forms Button Image has unwanted border

Tags: image, winforms, button

Unwanted border around `Button` when `Button.Image` property is set. Second image is when cursor is over yellow box.

[image][image]

When `button.ImageAlign` is set to `ContentAlingment.MiddleCenter` the border is still there but 1 pixel wide.

Red box should be 100x100, but is 95x95 (measured on screen shot).

Expected result is four squares with no gap between.

Problem don't exist when I use `BackgroundImage` property but then button don't gray out automatically when disabled.

Full code:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Shown += OnShown;
    }

    private Bitmap DrawFilledRectangle(int x, int y, Brush brush)
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(x, y);
        using (var graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            var imageSize = new Rectangle(0, 0, x, y);
            graph.FillRectangle(brush, imageSize);
        }
        return bmp;
    }

    private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        BackColor = Color.Wheat;

        var leftTop = new Button();
        var rightTop = new Button();
        var leftBottom = new Button();
        var rightBottom = new Button();

        var bmp1 = DrawFilledRectangle(100, 100, Brushes.Firebrick);
        var bmp2 = DrawFilledRectangle(100, 100, Brushes.ForestGreen);
        var bmp3 = DrawFilledRectangle(100, 100, Brushes.CornflowerBlue);
        var bmp4 = DrawFilledRectangle(100, 100, Brushes.Yellow);

        SetButton(leftTop, bmp1);
        SetButton(rightTop, bmp2);
        SetButton(leftBottom, bmp3);
        SetButton(rightBottom, bmp4);

        leftTop.Left = leftTop.Top = 10;

        rightTop.Left = leftTop.Left+ bmp1.Width;
        rightTop.Top = 10;

        leftBottom.Left = 10;
        leftBottom.Top = leftTop.Top + bmp1.Height;

        rightBottom.Left = leftBottom.Left + bmp1.Width;
        rightBottom.Top = rightTop.Top + bmp1.Height;

        Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { leftTop, rightTop, leftBottom,rightBottom });
    }

    private void SetButton(Button button, Bitmap bmp)
    {
        button.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
        button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        button.Image = bmp;
        button.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
        button.Margin = new Padding(0);
        button.Padding = new Padding(0);
        button.Size = bmp.Size;
    }
}
```

### Edit

I have pictures instead of filled boxes in real application.

Comment: If you don't want the control to *act* like a button then just don't use a Button control.  You can remove a lot of your code if you use a PictureBox instead.  Still has a Click event, displays a filled rectangle with the BackColor property, but without the hovering and focusing behavior.

Comment: But I want to have buttons and picture boxes. They do their job well, they just don't look good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
public class AppButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        if (Enabled)
        {
            pevent.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(Image, 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawImageDisabled(pevent.Graphics, Image, 0, 0, Color.Transparent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you set the FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0, it stills doesn't stretch it correctly.

So basically you have to do this:

```C#
SetButton(leftTop, bmp1, Color.Firebrick);
SetButton(rightTop, bmp2, Color.ForestGreen);
SetButton(leftBottom, bmp3, Color.CornflowerBlue);
SetButton(rightBottom, bmp4, Color.Yellow);

private void SetButton(Button button, Bitmap bmp, Color borderColor)
{
    button.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = borderColor;
    button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
    button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    button.Image = bmp;
    button.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    button.Margin = new Padding(0);
    button.Padding = new Padding(0);
    button.Size = bmp.Size;
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: I have pictures instead of filled boxes in real application, this is not solution for me.

Comment: Then at best with the Button route, you will have a 1 pixel transparent.  If you set the 'button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize=0` or if you like, you can just make your own custom button that derives from Button and override on the OnPaint() to do BitBlt that image you want to cover the whole surface.

Comment: I'll try set `BackgroundImage`, `Image` and transparent 1 pixel wide border. That should do the trick.

Comment: That would do it, but I thought you didn't want to use BackgroundImage.  You will need to set the FlatAppearance.BorderSize=0,  you can't set border color to Transparent.